# Calculating Virtual Memory page table and translation lookaside buffer

Tags: computer-science, virtual-memory, cpu-architecture

I am answering some problems related to virtual memory and would like some help in clarifying or confirming my understanding on how this stuff is done.

The questions are as follows:

> Given a byte-addressable system with 32 bit words, a virtual address space of 4 gigabytes,  a physical address space of 1 gigabyte, and a page size of 4 kilobytes. There is an assumption that page table entries are rounded up to 4 bytes.
>
> a) What is the size of the page table in bytes?
>
> b) Now assume that a 4-way set-associative translation lookaside buffer is implemented, with a total of 256 address translations.  Calculate the size of its tag and index fields.

My answers are as follows:

A:

> The size of the page table is equal to the number of entries in the page table multiplied by the size of the entries.
>
> The number of entries in the page table is equal to the memory size divided by the page size: 2^32/2^12=2^20.
>
> The size of the entries is equal to the word size minus the bits used for the number of entries in the page table: 32-20=12.
>
> Hence, the page table size is: (2^20) * 12 bits = 12582912 bits = 1572864 bytes

However, I found [this](http://www.d.umn.edu/~gshute/os/address-translation.xhtml#page-table-size) (under the heading of "Page Table Size"), which uses basically identical numbers.

> Page Table Size = ((virtual address space size)/(page size)) * (page table entry size)
>                    = (4 GB/4 KB) * 4 B = 4 MB

Which answer is correct?

Next, B:

> I am unsure of how to calculate part B. I believe that the Tag is calculated by adding the number of blocks, plus the offset, plus the index. This is a 4 way set associative, so there are 4 blocks in each set. The index is 8 bits because the base index size is 10 bits and is decreased by 2, also because it is a 4 way set associative. However, I am unaware of how to calculate the offset, which is needed to help calculate the tag.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For part a, you made two errors. First, the question specifically stated "page table entries are rounded up to 4 bytes". Second, the PTE contains the bits needed to determine the *physical* address based on the address being page aligned. In the described system, physical addresses are only 30 bits (1 GiB). Since that system uses 4KiB pages, the least significant 12 bits of the physical address in the PTE would be all zeros and so can be implicit. So just for the physical address 18 bits (30-12) are needed.

Aside from the desirability of rounding to a power of two number of bytes, most PTEs include additional data such as a valid bit, a modified bit, an accessed bit, and permission bits for user and supervisor modes; so even with a 512 MiB physical address space and 8 KiB pages (16 bits needed to indicate the physical address), one could not use 2 byte PTEs.

(It should be noted that no 32-bit processor would use a flat page table. For 32-bit addresses, hierarchical or linear page tables are generally used. These introduce a little extra space overhead for full occupancy and can require multiple memory accesses to find a translation, but in the common case of partial occupancy and dense allocation they use substantially less memory. This is particularly significant since most processors are designed for multiple address space OSes where each process has its own page table. Using almost half of physical memory [400 MiB] in page tables to support just 100 processes is understandably unattractive.)

For part b, you are correct that being 4-way set associative means that there are 4 blocks in each set and so 2 bits are subtracted from the number of bits needed for indexing based on the number of entries. However, log2(256) is 8 not 10, so only 6 bits are used for indexing the TLB.

In a data cache, the tag size would equal the number of address bits minus the number of index bits, minus the number of offset bits (within the cache block).

For a TLB, the virtual address is aligned to the size of the page (the least significant bits within the page are untranslated). For 4 KiB pages, this means that the 12 least significant bits are ignored. With a 32-bit virtual address, this leaves 20 bits.

That 6 of these bits are used for indexing has already been determined, so 14 bits are left.

For non-clustered TLB, each tag is associated with one translation. This would be equivalent to a data cache block size of 1 byte (i.e., 0 offset bits). Therefore, the tag (excluding any Address Space ID) would be 14 bits.

(In a clustered TLB [analogous to sectored cache blocks], two or more translations are provided for each "entry"--entry becomes a less clear term as it could refer to the translation entry or to the combination of the tag and multiple translations associated with that tag. [I suspect you appreciate such complexities not being part of these problems.])

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I understand part b completely now. I am a bit confused by your explanation of my errors in part a though. Am I off in calculating the number of entries in the page table?

Comment: @basil No, you are correct concerning the number of PTEs needed (for the assumed flat page table), but the number of bits per PTE is wrong both from the stated assumption in the problem and the number of bits required to express the physical address of a page. (I did mention that a flat page table is extremely unlikely; in that sense the size of the page table would be incorrect, but that is an issue with the problem's assumptions not with your understanding.)

Comment: I think I get you. So you are saying that the Entry Size would be 18 bits, per your explanation of the physical address above? And this would then effect my calculation of the page table (was my method of calculating it correct?).  The bit about rounding page table entries is still throwing me off, how would this effect the overall size, the entry size, and the number of page table entries?

Comment: @basil The physical address *portion* of the PTE would be 18 bits, but PTEs contain other data (as noted in the answer). PTE size is rounded up to a power of two size so that indexing the page table is simple (shift vs. multiply) and accesses are aligned to the access size. A 32-bit PTE will still take up 32 bits even if only 20-something are used. (The other bits may be reserved for future use, e.g., to extend the physical address space or to add caching attributes, or left for OS use.) Obviously 2^20*32bits is not 2^20*18bits.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.  I guess it makes sense. So the page table would be (2^20)*32 bits then? Is this sort of thing (rounding page table entries up) done quite often?

Comment: @basil Rounding up sizes is relatively common. E.g., the Intel 432 was odd in having bit-granular variable length instructions, aside from DSPs (and old or specialized ISAs) power-of-two register sizes are almost universal. Once one has power-of-two sized registers, conforming other software-visible data to such makes sense. In addition, leaving space for the future addition of features is desirable for anything interacting directly with software for the sake of compatibility.